# "else encountered without matching if" in action script 2

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

```
this.onEnterFrame = function()
{
        if(Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT))
        {
                asdf._x += 10;
        }else if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT))
        {       
                asdf._x -= 10;
        }else if (Key.isDown(Key.UP))
        {
                asdf._y -= 10;
        }else if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN))
        {
                asdf._y += 10;
        }
}
var i = 0;
this.onEnterFrame = function()
{
        else if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN))
    {            
        asdf._y += 5;
            }
            if (Key.isDown(Key.SPACE))
            {
                i++;
                _root.attachMovie("Bullet", "Bullet" + i,_root.getNextHighestDepth());
                _root["Bullet" + i]._x = asdf._x + 3;
                _root["Bullet" + i]._y = asdf._y
            }
}
```

Whenever i try to run this, i get the following error: "Scene=Scene 1, layer=Layer 1, frame=1, Line 21  'else' encountered without matching 'if'"

Comment: You have an else without an if as the first line of the onEnterFrame function

Answer (score 2):

```
var i = 0;
this.onEnterFrame = function()
{
    else if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN))
    {
```

You can't start a function with `else` without a corresponding `if`. What you mean *may* be just plain;

```
var i = 0;
this.onEnterFrame = function()
{
    if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN))
    {
```